# Substring in Java - length up to a value

Tags: java, string, substring

I'm trying to make a substring which lets me have up to 6 letters of a surname, however what I have here seems to throw an error when it finds a surname of less than 6 letters, I have been looking for hours for a solution with no sucess :/

```
id = firstName.substring (0,1).toLowerCase() + secondName.substring (0,6).toLowerCase();
System.out.print ("Here is your ID number: " + id);
```

It's the `.substring(0,6)`. I need it to be *up to* 6 letters not exactly 6.

The error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:27)
```

Answer (score 42):

Use

```
secondName.substring (0, Math.min(6, secondName.length()))
```

Comment: `Math.min(6, secondName.length())` is `6` if `secondName.length()>6`, it's `secondName.length()` in the other case.

Comment: `secondName.lenght()` gets the length of the String. `Math.min()` gets the lowest value,

this means that if the length of the string is lower than 6 that value is returned. But if the length of the string is higher than 6 than 6 will be returned.

Comment: @RolfSmit - The question was *I need it to be up to 6*.

Answer (score 6):

I prefer

```
secondName.length > 6 ? secondName.substring(0, 6) : secondName
```

Answer (score 5):

[Try the Apache Commons StringUtils class.](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html)

```
// This operation is null safe.
org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils.substring(secondName, 0, 6);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fix @ihebiheb

Answer (score 1):

This can be a solution:
Check length of surname and decide accordingly

```
if (secondName.length() >6)
id = firstName.substring (0,1).toLowerCase() + secondName.substring (0,6).toLowerCase(); 
else
id = firstName.substring (0,1).toLowerCase() + secondName.substring (0,secondName.length()).toLowerCase();

System.out.print ("Here is your ID number: " + id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Though you didn't provide the error, it was pretty easy to spot the problem:

```
 id = firstName.substring (0,1).toLowerCase() + secondName.substring (0,6<secondName.length()?6:secondName.length).toLowerCase();
 System.out.print ("Here is your ID number: " + id);
```

**EDIT** This might be more readable:

```
 id = firstName.substring (0,1).toLowerCase() + (6<secondName.length()?secondName.substring(0,6):secondName).toLowerCase();
 System.out.print ("Here is your ID number: " + id);
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll be getting a java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

You need to make sure the length is always less than the string length. Something like

```
int len = Math.min(6, secondName.length());
String id = firstName.substring (0,1).toLowerCase() + secondName.substring (0,len).toLowerCase();
```